# subtract two 4-digit numbers and obtain the sum of the digits always 18

Tags: divisibility

Let (abcd) and (dcba) be 4-digit numbers and

(abcd)-(dcba)= (xyzt)

show that the sum of the number (xyzt) is always 18.

I think we will use divisibility rules but i could not

succeed...

Comment: $1112 - 1111 = 1$ which seems to be a counterexample for your problem. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Spencer $1111$ is not the reversed digit sequence $dcba$ of $abcd=1112$. $a=2,b=c=d=1$ rather leads to $2111-1112=999$ and the claim is that $9+9+9=18$. Well ...

Comment: Maybe it is assumed that $\overline{xyzt}$ is a 4-digit number?

Comment: the digit number of (xyzt) is not important.but the sum is always 18...

Comment: 5112-2115=2997, 2+9+9+7=27 not 18

Answer (score 2):

Without additional condition, the claim is not true. For example, $9551-1559=7992$ and $1+9+9+2=27\ne 18$; or: $7317-7137=180$ and $0+1+8+0=9\ne 18$.
However, if we impose the *additional* condition that $a\ne d$ and $b\ne c$ in the four-digit number $\overline{abcd}$ (and of course that $\overline{abcd}>\overline{dcba}$), then the claim becomes true:

Recall that the digit sum of a number has the same remainder modulo $9$ as the original number. Thus $\overline{abcd}$ and $\overline{dcba}$ have the same remainder and their difference $\overline{xyzt}$ as well as its digit sum $s:=x+y+z+t$ must be multiples of $9$.

From $a\ne d$ and $\overline{abcd}>\overline{dcba}$ we find $a-d\ge 1$. Since at most one borrow can occur in each place, we conclude $a-d\ge x\ge a-d-1$. On the other hand, $t=10+d-a$ (and *here* a borrow *must* occur), so that $$9\le x+t\le 10.$$

Similarly, $y\in\{b-c-1,b-c,b-c+9,b-c+10\}$ and (as a borrow from the one's place must occur) $z\in\{c-b-1,c-b+9\}$ so that together with $0\le x+y\le 18$ we find
$$ y+z\in\{8,9,18\}$$
Thus $s\le 9$ is not possible and $s=27$ is possible only if $x+t=9$ and $y=z=9$. But $z=9$ is only possible with $b=c$, hence is excluded. We conclude that $$s=9.$$